# What is the definition of a fiber of a vector bundle in algebraic geometry?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory, complex-geometry, hodge-theory

I am learning the variations of Hodge structure, yet getting stuck at the very first beginning.

Let $S$ be a projective nonsingular variety over $\mathbb{C}$. I have seen that a **variation of Hodge structure** of weight $k$ on $S$ is the data

1. A $\mathbb{Q}$-local system $V$,
2. A decreasing separated exhaustive filtration $\{F^p\mathcal{V}\}_{p \in \mathbb{Z}}$ of holomorphic subbundles of $\mathcal{V} := V \otimes_{\underline{\mathbb{Q}}} \mathcal{O}_S$ such that for any $s \in S$, **the fiber** $(V_s, F^pV_s)$ is a Hodge structure of weight $k$ and the canonical flat connection $\nabla$ satisfies the Griffith transversality.

**Question 1**: I am quite confused on the meaning of the "**fiber**" $(V_s, F^pV_s)$. Could someone tell me the definition or provide a reference on what it means?

As I understand it, a $\mathbb{Q}$-local system $V$ is a locally constant sheaf of finite dimensional $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. *(I guess the dimensions locally are constant since $S$ is irreducible? Am I right?)*

I have been searching, and guessing that it might be $V_s := \mathcal{V}_s \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \kappa(s)$, where $\kappa(s)$ is the residue field of $s \in S$, and similar for $F^p \mathcal{V}$. Yet trying to be a Hodge structure, **it has to be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space**, but I cannot see why it is a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space. Moreover,

**Question 2**: what does the **subbundle** in the definition mean? And what does people mean by saying a "holomorphic bundle"?

As far as I can see, $\mathcal{V}$ is a locally free $\mathcal{O}_S$-module of finite rank since locally it looks like $\mathbb{Q}^{\oplus N} \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathcal{O}_S \cong \mathcal{O}_S^{\oplus n}$ if we ignore the sheafification. (I am a little uncertain on this, since I have heard people saying that it is coherent, yet seldomly they say it is locally free.) So does the "subbundle" mean a sub-$\mathcal{O}_S$-module that is still locally free?

Thank you all for answering and commenting!  :)  Sorry for being so stupid.

Comment: (1) V_s is just the stalk at s, if you wish to call it that. It is a vector space over $ \mathbb{Q} $, obviously isomorphic to the vector space defining the local system, albeit non-canonically, by choosing a trivialization.

Comment: (2) F is a sub-bundle of E if the quotient E/F is locally free.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you! By saying "V_s is just the stalk at s", do you mean $V_s$ is the stalk of the local system $V$, **instead of** the sheaf $\mathcal{V} := V \otimes_{\mathbb{Q}} \mathcal{O}_S$? Yet I am still confused at the subbundles, what does the **fiber** of $F^p \mathcal{V}$ at $s$ mean? Is it the base change $V_s \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{S,s}} \kappa(s)$? But how can it be a $\mathbb{Q}$-vector space, at the same time be the subspace of $V_s$? I can only see it is a $\kappa(s)$-vector space. Thank you!

Comment: ... And as for your second comment, it is the first time I saw the definition, could you provide some reference on this, so that I could carefully study things related to these.

Comment: I don't know why you're getting so confused, V_s itself is a vector space over Q. Any sheaf of abelian groups has a stalk at a point, the direct limit. Here $ V $ is a local system with stalk some vector space. It's just that vector space along with a filtration of the complexification, which gives you a Hodge structure. Vary the point, so it becomes a VHS.

Comment: What other explanation do you want for 'sub-bundle'? Honestly, all that I wrote is everything that there is to the definition.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Oh, I see! I have misunderstood the Hodge filtration. As you said, it is a filtration of the *complexification*. Stupid of me. And sorry to cause any confusion, I mean I haven't found the definition of a "subbundle" in Hartshorne's book, so I am here to ask. Sometimes I found that people may talk about concepts that are geometrically clear but are lacking the precise definition. So I have to guess. To avoid this, I am trying to know where I can found the precise definitions. Thank you for your kind reply!

Comment: no problem, you’re not stupid - I was just trying to understand where the confusion was. One can have a locally free subsheaf of a locally free sheaf, but it is not necessary for the quotient to be locally free (Think of the ideal sheaf of a divisor). A sub-bundle is the ‘legit’ case of a sub-vector bundle of a bigger one, i.e. the quotient is also a vector bundle.

Comment: @CraniumClamp Thank you! Now I see the point. :) Thank you so much!